# How to get command line arguments of an Eclipse 4 application from code

Tags: rcp, e4

I need to somehow get command line arguments of a running Eclipse 4 application. I'm working on a small application based on the Eclipse 4 RCP, but I thing, this problem is more common. I'm unable to find out, how to get from code of a product respectively of a plug-in the command line argumnets, the application have been executed with.

I need to use a custom command line parameter to pass on information to my code. Do anybody know a hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since E4 is using Equinox as runtime you can use the Platform class to get the application arguments.

```
Platform.getApplicationArgs()
```

See Javadoc:
http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Findex.html

Answer (score 4):

I've got it. It is not so intuitive, but it works for me. There is an instance implementing the `IApplicationContext` interface. (The interface depends on the `org.eclipse.equinox.app`.) The instance is reachable by the injection mechanism. The method `getArguments()` returns a map. But it does not return a map of some command line parameters and their values. It returns some map, where it is under the key `"application.args"` stored an array. Exampli gratia:

```
@PostConstruct
public void createControls(Composite parent, HtmlEditorService editorService, IApplicationContext iac) {
    System.out.println(iac.getArguments().get("application.args").getClass().getCanonicalName());
    ...
}
```

Then it prints out `java.lang.String[]`. However the array contains just my custom arguments instead all arguments. Fortunately it does not matter for me. I need to get my custom arguments only.

**Additional hint for a plug-in activator**

```
public class Aktivator implements BundleActivator {
    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        ServiceReference<?> ser = context.getServiceReference(IApplicationContext.class);
        IApplicationContext iac = (IApplicationContext)context.getService(ser);
        System.out.println(iac.getArguments().get("application.args").getClass().getCanonicalName());
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a constants `IApplicationContext.APPLICATION_ARGS` that can be used instead of the `"application.args" string.